# localization help need for java android app

Tags: java, android, localization

I need help to localization part of the following java android app in every line after `AppConstant.PAYPAL,` I need to localize like

```
"Withdraw 10$ with PayPal / 10000 Credits"
```

to

```
getString(R.string.pay1)
```

And I added

```
<string name="pay1">Withdraw 10$ with PayPal / 10000 Credits</string>
```

to my strings.xml but it fails

I want

```
arr.add(new Reward("res.cloudinary.com/ddtivxyzk/image/upload/v149334941‌​1/…;, AppConstant.PAYPAL, "Withdraw 10$ with PayPal / 10000 Credits", "10000", "10"));
```

to be like:

```
arr.add(new Reward("res.cloudinary.com/ddtivxyzk/image/upload/v149334941‌​1/…;, AppConstant.PAYPAL, getString(R.string.pay1), "10000", "10"));
```

But it don't work

```
package com.earn.money.db;

import com.earn.money.constant.AppConstant;
import com.earn.money.model.Reward;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DataProvider {

    public static List<Reward> getRewardList() {
        ArrayList<Reward> arr = new ArrayList<>();

        arr.add(new Reward("http://res.cloudinary.com/ddtivxyzk/image/upload/v1493349411/paypal_e1s9xf.png", AppConstant.PAYPAL, "Withdraw 10$ with PayPal / 10000 Credits", "10000", "10"));
        arr.add(new Reward("http://res.cloudinary.com/ddtivxyzk/image/upload/v1493349411/paypal_e1s9xf.png", AppConstant.PAYPAL, "Withdraw 25$ with PayPal / 25000 Credits", "25000", "25"));
        arr.add(new Reward("http://res.cloudinary.com/ddtivxyzk/image/upload/v1493349411/paypal_e1s9xf.png", AppConstant.PAYPAL, "Withdraw 50$ with PayPal / 50000 Credits", "50000", "50"));

        arr.add(new Reward("http://res.cloudinary.com/ddtivxyzk/image/upload/v1493349714/googleplay_v8rwwu.png", AppConstant.GOOGLE_PLAY, "Gift Card 10$ with Google Play / 10000 Credits", "10000", "10"));
        arr.add(new Reward("http://res.cloudinary.com/ddtivxyzk/image/upload/v1493349714/googleplay_v8rwwu.png", AppConstant.GOOGLE_PLAY, "Gift Card 25$ with Google Play / 25000 Credits", "25000", "25"));
        arr.add(new Reward("http://res.cloudinary.com/ddtivxyzk/image/upload/v1493349714/googleplay_v8rwwu.png", AppConstant.GOOGLE_PLAY, "Gift Card 50$ with Google Play / 50000 Credits", "50000", "50"));

        arr.add(new Reward("http://res.cloudinary.com/ddtivxyzk/image/upload/v1493349711/amazon_eelqab.png", AppConstant.AMAZON, "Gift Card 10$ with Amazon / 10000 Credits", "10000", "10"));
        arr.add(new Reward("http://res.cloudinary.com/ddtivxyzk/image/upload/v1493349711/amazon_eelqab.png", AppConstant.AMAZON, "Gift Card 25$ with Amazon / 25000 Credits", "25000", "25"));
        arr.add(new Reward("http://res.cloudinary.com/ddtivxyzk/image/upload/v1493349711/amazon_eelqab.png", AppConstant.AMAZON, "Gift Card 50$ with Amazon / 50000 Credits", "50000", "50"));

        arr.add(new Reward("http://res.cloudinary.com/ddtivxyzk/image/upload/v1493349709/webmoney_jptfkw.jpg", AppConstant.WEBMONEY, "Withdraw 10$ with WebMoney / 10000 Credits", "10000", "10"));
        arr.add(new Reward("http://res.cloudinary.com/ddtivxyzk/image/upload/v1493349709/webmoney_jptfkw.jpg", AppConstant.WEBMONEY, "Withdraw 25$ with WebMoney / 25000 Credits", "25000", "25"));
        arr.add(new Reward("http://res.cloudinary.com/ddtivxyzk/image/upload/v1493349709/webmoney_jptfkw.jpg", AppConstant.WEBMONEY, "Withdraw 50$ with WebMoney / 50000 Credits", "50000", "50"));

        return arr;
    }

 }
```

Comment: What do you mean "it fails"?  An error?

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what you exactly want

Comment: like i want arr.add(new Reward("http://res.cloudinary.com/ddtivxyzk/image/upload/v1493349411/paypal_e1s9xf.png", AppConstant.PAYPAL, "Withdraw 10$ with PayPal / 10000 Credits", "10000", "10")); to be like arr.add(new Reward("http://res.cloudinary.com/ddtivxyzk/image/upload/v1493349411/paypal_e1s9xf.png", AppConstant.PAYPAL, getString(R.string.pay1), "10000", "10")); but it don't work

Comment: with my code `getString(R.string.pay1)`  igot 2 errors  `Cannot resolve method getString(?)`  `Cannot resolve symbol R `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by adding 
`import com.earn.money.R`
to the java file
Thanks to all who answered me and tried to help me

Answer (score 0):

You need this

```
context.getResources().getString(R.string.pay1)
```

But please show your error log.

Comment: with my code getString(R.string.pay1) igot 2 errors
Cannot resolve method getString(?)
Cannot resolve symbol R

with your code context.getResources().getString(R.string.pay1) igot 2 errors
Cannot resolve symbol context
Cannot resolve symbol R